# ARMClient.exe not working in azure powershell workflow (hydrid)

Tags: powershell, azure, automation, hybrid, runbook

I am trying to execute the ARMClient.exe from my Azure Powershell Workflow runbook on Hydrid worker. 
Its throwing me the folloing error:

Cannot find the 'ARMClient.exe' command. If this command is defined as a workflow, ensure it is defined before the workflow that calls it. If it is a command intended to run directly within Windows PowerShell (or is not available on this system), place it in an InlineScript: 'InlineScript { ARMClient.exe }'

I have followed https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/leveraging-the-oms-search-api-in-an-azure-automation-runbook/
post step by step.

Can anyone help me resolve this error.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I restarted the Hybrid worker VM, and it started to recognize the command ARMClient.exe from azure runbook!

Silly of me, I should have restarted the VM before posting the question here :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you do the Hybrid worker setup correctly?

It looks like from the error message that it cannot locate the ARMClient.exe, usually meaning it's not installed / cannot be resolved in the $env:path (paths on the machine).

Did you install chocolatey and the ArmClient package (using choco install armclient) on the worker? Have you verified that the Armclient is installed?

For details installing chocolatey see : https://chocolatey.org/

For details on installing the armclient : https://github.com/projectkudu/ARMClient